# Troubles with CMake and Assimp

Tags: c++, cmake

I have the latest assimp source code (5.0.1 release), I have built it with CMake and installed using `cmake --install`. Now I am trying to add it to my CMake project: `find_package(Assimp REQUIRED Assimp)` - at this moment it configures fine. The problems started when I tried to add

```
target_link_libraries(
    MyProj PRIVATE
    Assimp::Assimp
)
```

And I get the following error:

```
[cmake]   target "MyProj" links to target "Assimp::Assimp" but the target
[cmake]   was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
[cmake]   target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
```

After some research, I've tried `target_link_libraries(MyProj PRIVATE ${ASSIMP_LIBRARIES})`, this time I got a compile error, and when I displayed the value of the ${ASSIMP_LIBRARIES} variable (command: `message("${ASSIMP_LIBRARIES}")`) I got: `assimp-vc142-mt.dll` - it contains .dll name, even without full path. Have a lot of troubles with assimp, could anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: I am doing that on Windows 10, using Visual Studio compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having any knowledge of assimp, I think what you want is this:

```cpp
target_link_libraries(MyProj PRIVATE assimp::assimp)
```

As far as I know, CMake target names are case sensitive and the `assimp::assimp` alias target is created [here](https://github.com/assimp/assimp/blob/v5.0.1/code/CMakeLists.txt#L1106) with lowercase *a*.

Comment: Whaaaat?! One day of looking for a solution and the problem was about uppercase letters?! Thank you a lot for your help. At least now this project is configured without errors. But now I get a compile-time error: ```..\lib\bin\assimp-vc142-mt.dll : fatal error LNK1107```, because in generated Visual Studio solution in Linker Input section I have ..\lib\bin\assimp-vc142-mtd.dll instead of .lib. But still thanks a lot!